# audio streaming using python (pyaudio) and a web interface

Tags: python, sockets, audio, networking, pyaudio

So excited for My first post in Stackoverflow! :)

**Q:** I'm recording and processing sounds using python (pyaudio + scipy). now one important thing that I need, is the ability to streaming this processed audio(that's in form of python Variables),Over wifi (or bluetooth). User clients that connecting to my server, should can play that sound for Live. But really I haven't any background about web/net based application in python.

**I'm thinking this way :**
Maybe linux should establish a server(become a Access point) and give access to users for playing streamed audio using a simple html page! This webpage maybe need just a **play button** that when client click on that,and live streaming audio will be played!

Can anybody guide me in right way?